# Quick way to sqrt squared values in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following code

```
a = tf.constant([3.0, 8.1])
squared_sum = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(a))
sqrt = tf.math.sqrt(squared_sum)
```

Something obvious such us `sqrt(3.0**2 + 8.1**2)` has to be made in 3 steps (square, reduce_sum and sqrt). Is there any other faster way in Tensorflow?

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure that you can use `tf.math.sqrt(3.0**2 + 8.1**2)` directly if you want to.

Comment: @Lescurel but in the case of being `Tf.Tensor()` instead of just numbers?

Comment: It still applies..

Comment: @AloneTogether but that would lead to a output of `(n, m)` dimensions and not an output of a number instead, due to the ommision of `reduce_sum()`

Comment: you can reshape your output?

Comment: @AloneTogether yes, but that would be same as using those 3 steps above. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing that code

Comment: Even if there were some kind of abstraction. Under the hood, it would still be the same operations.

Comment: There is one `Tensorflow API` available, called [tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/RootMeanSquaredError) which will fit to this requirement. It will do mean of the values, except reduce_sum.